# valuebox missing true/false statement

Tags: if-statement, shiny, render

I am attempting to have two if else statements in a renderValuebox in shiny  R. Here's the code:

```
observe({
  a <- which(blkname==input$e0)
  start <- input$dateRange[1]
  end <- input$dateRange[2]
  confInt <- input$CI
  inc <- input$increment
  output$Name <- renderText(paste0("Overview of ",input$e0," block"))
  start1 <- as.character(format(input$dateRange[1], format="%B %d %Y"))
  end1 <- as.character(format(input$dateRange[2], format="%B %d %Y"))
  output$Head <- renderText(paste0("Distribution of dry matter across ", input$e0, " between ",start1, " and ", end1))
  pts$DryMatter <- pts$DryMatter+(pts$Amend*inc)
  pts$DryMatter <- round(pts$DryMatter, digits=2)
  grap <- pts[which(pts$Date>start&pts$Date<end),]
  grap <- grap[which(grap$paddock==a),]
  grap$DryMatter<- round(grap$DryMatter, digits=2)
  yup <- round(mean(grap$DryMatter), digits=2)
  nump <- nrow(grap)
  grapdevdm <- grap[which(grap$Amend==min(grap$Amend)),]
  grapdev <- sd(grapdevdm$DryMatter)
  grapsampnum <- nrow(grapdevdm)
  grapdevmean <- mean(grapdevdm$DryMatter)
  cv <- (grapdev/grapdevmean)*100
  sampReq <-(1.7*1.7)*(cv*cv)/((100-confInt)^2)
```

~

```
  output$treenum <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      paste0(nrow(grap), "Trees sampled out of ", sampReq, "required."),
      if(nrow(grap)>=sampReq){ 
        icon = icon("thumbs-up", lib = "glyphicon")}else
        {icon = icon("thumbs-down", lib = "glyphicon")},
      if(nrow(grap)>=sampReq){ color = "green"} else {colour = "red"}
    )
  })
```

I am receiving Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

However both if else is completed, maybe I am missing something.

Cheers,

Comment: Somethings is null here so you can perform a logical operation on a `null` value, you need to check what is `null`. Print out the `grap`, `sampReq` before you apply the `if` statement

Comment: Unfortunately  the grap and sampReq are values that are taken in from an Observe and input$ function, so they vary based on a users selection on the application. The original code had a value of 20 instead of the "sampReq" variable. I attempted passing another variable that is also initiated in observe however is not influenced by input$ and it still didn't like this... Is this a limitation of valueBox?

Comment: You should post more of your code as I am speculating here only

Comment: It seems you mean that `grap` and `sampReq` are reactive. However it seems that you do not use `reactiveValues`.

Comment: I have posted more code, it may not be helpful since the application is quiet large at the moment and goes through MANY data processing. Stephane I have never used reactiveValues before, this is new to me!